# Webgrid disappear while clicking pagination in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a grid as a partialview in my main cshtml.When i click page number in the gird,the grid is disappearing. any suggestion?

Devices.csthml(partialview)

Even i have div my-grid in the partial view.

```
<div id="my-grid">
    @{

        var grid = new WebGrid(
                               canPage: true,
                               canSort: true,
                             rowsPerPage: 3,
                             ajaxUpdateContainerId: "my-grid");

            grid.Bind(Model, rowCount: Model.Count(), autoSortAndPage: true);



        @grid.GetHtml(
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "my-grid" },
        tableStyle: "grid1",
        headerStyle: "header",
        rowStyle: "row",
        footerStyle: "footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
        columns: grid.Columns(
                                grid.Column("ObjectOfServiceName", "Device Name", style: "textCol"),
                                grid.Column("SerialNumber", "Serial Number", style: "textCol"),
                                grid.Column("ContractIdentifier", "Contract Identifier", style: "textCol"),
                                grid.Column("ServiceLevelCode", "Service Level", style: "textCol"),
                                grid.Column("UserDeviceDescription", "Device Grouping", style: "textCol"),
                                grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Upgrade", "DeviceUpgradePartial", new { objectOfServiceId = item.ObjectOfServiceId, serviceContractId = item.ServiceContractId, serialNumber = item.SerialNumber, objectOfServiceName = item.ObjectOfServiceName, serviceLevelId = item.ServiceLevelId, deviceGroupingId = item.DeviceGroupingId }, new { @class = "upgradeLink", title = "Upgrade Device" })" </text>, style: "colOperation"),
                                grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Update", "DeviceUpdatePartial", new { objectOfServiceId = item.ObjectOfServiceId, serviceContractId = item.ServiceContractId, serialNumber = item.SerialNumber, objectOfServiceName = item.ObjectOfServiceName, serviceLevelId = item.ServiceLevelId, deviceGroupingId = item.DeviceGroupingId }, new { @class = "updateLink", title = "Update Device" })" </text>, style: "colOperation"),
                                grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink("ReassignDeviceGroup", "ReassingDeviceGroupingPartial", new { objectOfServiceId = item.ObjectOfServiceId, serviceContractId = item.ServiceContractId, serialNumber = item.SerialNumber, objectOfServiceName = item.ObjectOfServiceName, serviceLevelId = item.ServiceLevelId, deviceGroupingId = item.DeviceGroupingId }, new { @class = "reassingDeviceGroupLink", title = "Update Device" })" </text>, style: "colOperation")

                            ), mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)




    }
</div>
```

Main.cshtml:

```
 <tr>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {

                    <td>Select customer Name</td>
                    <td>

                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.customer_id, new SelectList(Model.customerList, "customer_id", "customer_business_name"))
                        <input type="hidden" id="hdnCustomerName" name="hdnCustomerName" />
                        <input type="hidden" id="hdnShowHideCustInfo" name="hdnShowHideCustInfo" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Go" name="Go" id="Go" />
                       </td>                   

                }
            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>




        @if (Model.objectOfServiceListDevice != null)
        {
            @Html.Partial("Devices", Model.objectOfServiceListDevice)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try replacing this:

```
@if (Model.objectOfServiceListDevice != null)
{
    @Html.Partial("Devices", Model.objectOfServiceListDevice)
}
```

With this:

```
<div id="myGrid">
    @Html.Partial("Devices", Model.objectOfServiceListDevice)
</div>
```